# VIM un-mapped keys enter text into the buffer

Tags: vim

When I press a key such as `F2` while in insert mode, `<F2>` will be entered into the buffer. I would like to use the function keys as hotkeys however this is impracticable when I always need to go and delete the piece of text.

Is there a way to disable this in vim? I couldn't find anyone else with this problem so I am quite stuck with this one.

Edit: ps Im using VIM 8.0 in gui mode.

Comment: F2 is pretty far away from the home row, i guess mostly every vim user does prefer keys which are nearer then F2.

Comment: @snap These are hotkeys detected by another program, I'm picking keys so far away for the reason that they won't interfere with any of vims keys since vim doesn't use them.

Comment: you should choose a lead key then you can take all other keys for your mappings.

Comment: @snap These are hotkeys I don't only use while using vim, It would be redundant to define what each key does twice.

Comment: @MukeshIngham i guess now i got it. i have add an answer hot to map f2 to no operations, so it will not print f2 any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map the key to no operations for doing nothing if pressed in insert mode. So, i guess this would do the trick:

```
inoremap <F2> <Nop>
```

If you prefer that F2 should do nothing (vim specific) in all vim modes it would be:

```
noremap <F2> <Nop>
```